# Angular2 Load Child route without reloading parent

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-routing

I am just starting with angular2 and have come into an issue. When navigating to a child route when the current view is the parent route, the parent route still reloads.

I have this route configuration for my users page.

```
const userRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: ':username',
        component: UserProfileComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                component: UserFeedComponent
            },
            {
                path: 'news',
                component: UserNewsComponent
            }
        ]
    },
];

export const userRouting = RouterModule.forChild(userRoutes);
```

The user-profile.component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'user-profile',
    templateUrl: 'app/+users/user-profile.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['app/+users/user-profile.component.css']
})
export class UserProfileComponent {
    constructor(private users: UserService, private route: ActivatedRoute, private titleService: TitleService) {
    }

    private user: User;
    private title: string;

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log("init");
        this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
            let username = params['username'];
            this.users.resolveUsername(username).subscribe(user => {
                this.user = user;
                this.users.user.next(user)
            });
        });

        // use the titleService to subscribe to a change in title. Child route handles title.
        this.titleService.title.subscribe(title => this.title = title)
    }
}
```

And the template for UserProfileComponent:

```
<div class="profile-header grid-content medium-6 medium-offset-3 small-12" *ngIf="user">
    <img src="{{user?.picture}}" class="thumbnail avatar">
    <div class="profile-info">
        <h1>{{user?.name}}</h1>
        <h4><a [routerLink]="['/users', user.username]"  *ngIf="user"> @{{user.username}}</a></h4>
    </div>
    <ul class="menu-bar">
        <li><a [routerLink]="['/users', user.username]"  *ngIf="user"><i class="fa fa-rss"></i> Feed</a> </li>
        <li><a [routerLink]="['news']"><i class="fa fa-newspaper-o"></i> News</a> </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<hr>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

So if I am at the UserFeedComponenet and navigate to the UserNewsComponenet the whole UserProfileComponent reloads. This slows down the page load since the user is loaded again in the `UserProfileComponent`'s `ngOnInit()` through an HTTP request.

Is this a quirk of angular2 or am I doing something wrong? If the former then I'll create an issue for it. It's very inefficient to do this although I appreciate that in some cases you might need to but in this case I do not.

Comment: Should `path: ':username'` be `path: '/username'`?

Comment: @Z.Z. as per the angular2 [docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html), the colon represents a url parameter. So that username is dynamic

Comment: I'm using 2.4.1 and still having this issue.  The router demo on the docs site doesn't exhibit this behavior though.  It's definitely something in my code but I don't know what.

Comment: Not sure what fixed it but I did fix this.  Either bad logic in my activatedRoute or because I was setting default values for arrays in my reducers to null instead of and empty array `[]`, or both.

Comment: Were you able to fix this?